# Find limit with alternating sign

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Please, help proceed further

$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{(-2)^n+3^n}{(-2)^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}=\lim_{n \to 
+\infty}\frac{(-2)^n}{(-2)^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}+\lim_{n \to 
+\infty}\frac{3^n}{(-2)^{n+1}+3^{n+1}}=\lim_{n \to 
+\infty}\frac{1}{-2+3*(-1.5)^{n}}+\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{1}{(-2)*{(\frac{-2}{3})}^{n}+3}$

Answer (score 2):

Divide  numerator and denominator by $3^{n}$ and take the limit. The $\pm $ signs won't matter now and you get the limit as $\frac {0+1} {0+3}= \frac 1 {3}$.